# Is remote start and cluster connected to 8.4in radio?

Tags: jeep, electronics, grand-cherokee, remote-start, instrument-cluster

Just to get to the point, my car was broken into 2 days ago and the 8.4 inch navigation/radio was ripped out and stolen. I have to drive my car to/from work for a few days before I can get it fixed and I noticed that my remote start doesn't work and my cluster occasionally says one of my headlights went out or blind spot is unavailable (restarting the vehicle fixes this but it still occasionally goes off).

I'm wondering if the remote start and cluster is connected to that 8.4in radio that was stolen or there's a separate module somewhere under the steering wheel? Does the radio monitor problems in the car and display it on the cluster?

Thank you for your input!

P.S. Fyi... Apparently in newer Jeeps, if the rear window is broken the alarm doesn't go off as long as doors aren't opened :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the radio system in Jeeps are closely tied to the security system in the vehicle. It has something to do with the door chimes, air bags, and parts of the security (incl your remote start). When the thief removed your radio, they probably killed/disabled the remote start since the way that it's all connected requires your radio to be inline.

If you get a new radio installed with the proper harness then there is a decent chance (assuming the thief didn't damage the remote start components) that a few of those problems may get resolved.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. From my experience, most of the remote starters are located under the steering wheel and don't connect to the radio. Do you by any chance know if the radio also knows when the headlights went out? I get those error messages on my cluster and wonder if it receives the warning from the radio.

Comment: You're correct. I used to install car audio and I remember that there is an extra component inside of the factory radio. When you change this radio, the component is taken out and as a result an aftermarket harness needs to have this component still wired inline through the radio harness. Otherwise, you'll get check engine or airbag lights and all kinds of other crazy things can happen.
I don't think the radio affected your headlights, but it possibly affected your remote start with is likely tied into the security system which is tied into the headlights.